# set spacing among elements within button javafx

Tags: button, javafx, element, spacing

I want to specify spacing between two elements within JavaFX Buttons, Here is the Code :

```
    ImageView fiv = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/map.png"));
    fiv.setFitHeight(20);
    fiv.setPreserveRatio(true);

    Button cr = new Button( "Crop", fiv);
```

Here I want to Specify Spacing Between "Crop" and fiv, How can i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [graphicTextGap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphicTextGap-double-) property of the button.

Comment: Thanks, this is the thing i wanted

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, you can call the `setGraphicTextGap()` method to adjust the gap:

```
btnSaveUser.setGraphicTextGap(8.0);
```

I prefer to define my styles in an external CSS file, however.

If anybody is looking for a FXML equivalent, here it is:

```
.btnSaveUserClass {
    -fx-graphic-text-gap: 8.0;
}
```

The style class `btnSaveUserClass` must be applied to a button in the FXML file:

```
<Button fx:id="btnSaveUser" mnemonicParsing="true" text="_Save user"
                styleClass="btnSaveUserClass" onAction="#onSaveUserAction"/>
```